# SQL trigger to check previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have a trigger on table `tblA` if the status is `closed` it inserts a record to table `tblB`. The below code is working, but I want it to be executed only if the previous status was NOT `closed`. How can I check it?

```
ON tblA
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO tblB 
        (a_id, action, usr)
        select a.ID, 'closed', a.usr
        from tblA a
    WHERE a.Status LIKE 'closed';  
    END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trigger in SQL Server is always suspect if it fails to access either `inserted` or `deleted` (or both), since those are the pseudo-tables that give you the details of *what changed*.

You want something like:

```
INSERT INTO tblB 
    (a_id, action, usr)
    select a.ID, 'closed', a.usr
    from inserted a
            inner join
         deleted d
            on a.ID = d.ID
WHERE a.Status = 'closed'
  AND d.Status != 'closed';
```

Comment: So if one would modify a record, then the "old" values are being stored in `deleted` even if I trigger it `AFTER UPDATE`?

Comment: @fishmong3r - yes, for an update `deleted` contains the old values and `inserted` contains the new values.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot.